# How to tell when it is done the scroll in ScrollViewer?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I have a ScrollViewer with some elements, such as a picture.

```
 <ScrollViewer> 
    <Image x:Name="FlipViewImages" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Width="341" Height="236" Margin="0"> 
    <Button x:Name="MostraD1" Click="MostraD1_Click" Grid.Row="4" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Column="1" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Style="{StaticResource BottoneCuore}" Margin="2,0,0,0">
       <Button.Content>
             <TextBlock Text="MOSTRA DESCRIZIONE" FontSize="9" Foreground="Black" TextWrapping="Wrap" Height="26" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
        </Button.Content>
     </Button>
     <Button x:Name="MostraD2" Click="MostraD2_Click" Grid.Row="4" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Column="1" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Style="{StaticResource BottoneCuore}" Margin="0,0,60,0" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
         <Button.Content>
             <TextBlock Text="MOSTRA DESCRIZIONE" FontSize="9" Foreground="Black" TextWrapping="Wrap" Height="26" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
         </Button.Content>
     </Button>
</ScrollViewer>
```

you can tell when the ScrollViewer is done scroll down and the image is no longer visible?
In that case, I wanted to show the picture in another part of the Grid

Comment: Check this out : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21586381/detect-when-scrollviewer-has-stopped-scrolling

Comment: Am I wrong or is not available the event ScrollChanged on Windows Phone 8.1?